# Bind model to radio buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I have a report model that needs a date. he date can either be Today, Yesterday or a date range.

```
public class DateModel
{        
    public bool Today { get; set; }
    public bool Yesterday { get; set; }
    public bool DateRange { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

This model is bound to a view. radio buttons for Today,Yesterday,DateRange and text boxes for Start and End date.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButton("SelectedDate", "Yes", true, new { postData= "Today" }) Today
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButton("SelectedDate", "No", false, new { postData= "Yesterday" }) Yesterday
    </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButton("SelectedDate", "No", false, new { postData= "CallDateRange" }) Call Date Range
    </td>
</tr>
```

When the view is posted back, how can I get what radio button was selected?

Comment: This will greatly depending on how you're rending your radio buttons, and how the view is binding. Can you edit your post with the region of your radio buttons?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at your code, there maybe a better way overall. First, create an enumeration of the radio button types/values that you have available:

```
public enum DateEnum {
    Today,
    Yesterday,
    DateRange
}
```

Then modify your `DateModel` to use that enum

```
public class DateModel
{        
    public DateEnum SelectedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Lastly, update your view that your binding with to use the enum while using `RadioButtonFor()`

```
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedDate, DateEnum.Today) Today
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedDate, DateEnum.Yesterday) Yesterday
    </td>
</tr>    
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SelectedDate, DateEnum.DateRange) Call Date Range
    </td>
</tr>
```

Then on the form submission, you would look at the `SelectedDate` to determine which radio button the user has selected.

Comment: Thanks. but the selectedDate value is always DateRange? Is there a reason for this? Where did I go wrong?  Thanks

Comment: I setup a small test project on my machine, with the code and it works. I'd take a look at what is being posted from the browser using the developer tools in the browser or Fiddler to see what the browser is reporting to the application. Also make sure you don't have another form element on the page with the same name/value.

Comment: Thanks Steve. How can I change the name using this syntax?

Comment: The only way would be to change the `SelectedDate` property on `DateMode;`. If you change the name from "SelectedDate" to "Foobar" using Javascript or manually setting it, MVC won't know how to automatically bind the form post to the `DateModel`.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify your model like this:

```
public enum DateType {
   Today,
   Yesterday,
   DateRange 
}

public class DateModel
{        
    public DateType DateType { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

And use it in view:

```
@model DateModel    

@Html.BeginForm("ProcessForm") {    

    @* Populate radio *@

    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.DateType , DateType.Today) Today
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.DateType , DateType.Yesterday) Yesterday
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.DateType , DateType.DateRange) DateRange

    @* Range *@

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartDate ) Start date
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.EndDate  ) End date

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

Pass model to controller

```
public ActionResult ProcessForm(DateModel model) { // here you get model from form
   // .. 
}
```